# Content error fundamental about friend declaration in c++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, private, friend

I just don't get it, what is wrong in this friend declaration, first error msg:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:34:7: error: 'void steuerung::exe_testa(testa)' is private
test.cpp:48:15: error: within this context
```

The problem is being solved, when the constructor in testa's class declaration is removed. But I need a constructor. Can anyone please help me? Really thank YOU.

```
#include <iostream>

class steuerung;
class testb;
class testa;

class testa
{
friend class steuerung;
public:

private:
double a_;
double b_;
};

class testb
{
friend class steuerung; 
public:
testb(double a, double b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}

private:
double a_;
double b_;
};

class steuerung
{
friend class testa; 
friend class testb; 
void exe_testa(testa t_) { t_.b_++; }
//template<class t> void exe(t *t_) { std::cout << t_->a_ << std::endl; }
};




int main ()
{
std::cout << "Laeuft zumindest an.." << std::endl;

testa a;

steuerung s;
s.exe_testa(a);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`exe_testa` is private, so can only be called from member functions of `steuerung`, member functions of classes that are friends of `steuerung`, and friend functions of `steuerung`. `main` is none of those, so the call isn't legal.

Comment: Argh damn it, haven't thought of this. I have assumed class members are public by default.. Thank you!

Comment: @user1456766 - right. The default access for a class is private; for a struct it's public.